# Regular expression with positive lookahead/lookbehind

Tags: regex

How I can match all the below strings with a single regular expression?

This is the regular expression I've tried: `(?<=.+)site(?=.+)`

Note that simpler regular expressions might do the job, but the whole point of this is to learn that what the `(?<=.+)` and `(?=.+)` parts of the regular expression do.

```
locationAsite1
locationAsiteNumber1
locationAsiteNumber01
locationAsite01
locationBsite.01
locationB.site.02
(locationB)site.02
<locationB>site<03>s
..locationB..site<03>
```

Comment: The capabilities of regular expression libraries are quite varied (JavaScript does not handle positive/negative look-behind assertions, for instance).

Answer (score 5):

Your regex may also written as,

```
(?<=.)site(?=.)
```

which means, the string `site` must be preceded and followed by atleast one character.

Most languages won't support variable length lookbehind except the `C#` family.

```
(?<=.+)site(?=.+)
```

means the substring `site` must be preceded and followed by one or more chars. That is, it would match the string `site` only if it's at the middle not if it's present at the start or at the end.

Answer (score 3):

**Positive lookbehind** means that the expression in `(<= )` must be matched.

For example here if you say `(?<=A)site` the it will select those `site` with has `A` before it. Though `A` won't be selected by the regex, it only ensures that `A` comes before the `site`.

---

**Positive lookahead** is same as positive lookbehind just that the expression must be followed after the match.

Example: writing `site(?=1)` will match those `site` which has `1` immediately followed after it. As positive lookbehind it will not select `1` but only will ensure that those matches of `site` are made that actually are `site1`.

---

Your case of (?<=.)site(?=.) is not good for example since it will match all the `site` in your input.

So using `(?<=A)site(?=0)` will only match the site in the line `locationAsite01` since `site` has `A` preceding it and 0 following it.